# Get Volume GUID from Partition number in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, guid, winpe

I am looking for some kind help regarding below query.

I am trying to write (using `WriteFile()`) to a windows disk partition within a `Windows PE` environment by opening a disk handle and seeking to the partition starting offset.

`WriteFile()` is returning error code 5 (`ACCESS DENIED`).
 
I believe it is because the application has not locked the volume before writing to the volume.
My application has only the partition number as input. The ioctl `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` needs a volume handle which is returned by `CreateFile()` and this needs a volume `GUID` as parameter.
 
So how do I get the volume `GUID` via the partition number?

Regards.

Comment: Your question is highly convoluted, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: FWIW, the `FSTCL_LOCK_VOLUME` control does in fact work on `PhysicalDrive0` so it might also work on `Harddisk0Partition1`.  That's probably the simplest solution for in-house work.

Comment: Failing that, you might need to enumerate the volumes using FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume and then I *think* you could use the [SetupAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550897(v=vs.85).aspx) or the [PNP Configuration Manager API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549717(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine the disk and partition numbers for each volume.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually re-reading your question it sounds as if you're using a handle to `PhysicalDrive0` to do the actual work, so you should probably call `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` using that same handle.  The only catch is that this will lock all the volumes on that drive rather than just the one you want - but conversely, you probably can't write via `PhysicalDrive0` unless all the volumes are locked anyway.

Comment: @Harry . Thanks a lot. I tried handle to PhysicalDrive0 and then FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME.  WriteFile() sometimes still returns access denied error. But with handle to Harddisk0Partition1 it always works. Would the pathname of type Harddisk0Partition1 work in all environments?

Comment: I believe so, but since it isn't documented there's no way to be certain.